# Gesture detector onTap issue

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a gesture detector with an `onTap` function where it's supposed to remove an item from the list and after it has done that, A modal Bottom sheet should appear saying that the list item has been deleted, however, this does not work. The modal sheet is wrapped in `Future.delayed` so It only appears after 500 milliseconds. The only time where the issue does not persist is when I remove the `Future.delayed`.

How can I resolve this? Any help would be really appreciated

The gesture detector:

```
GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            alarmController.alarmList
                .removeAt(index);
          });
          Future.delayed(
              Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              () async {
            await showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                builder:
                    (BuildContext context) {
                  return Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[800],
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 10.0, top: 10.0),
                    height: 40.0,
                    child: Text(
                      "Deleted a task",
                      style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          color:
                              Colors.white70),
                    ),
                  );
                });
          });
          Future.delayed(
              const Duration(
                  milliseconds: 1900), () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          });
        },
        child: ListTile(
          minLeadingWidth: 30.0,
          contentPadding:
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 0.0),
          leading: const Icon(
            Icons.delete_outline,
            color: Colors.white70,
          ),
          title: Text(
            "Delete",
            style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                color: Colors.white70),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Error message:

```
Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
E/flutter (21624): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
E/flutter (21624): To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
```

Comment: Can you share the error message. I am guessing that since you are using Future.delayed, the context passed to modalBottomSheet might be stale.

Comment: I updated the question with the error message

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by declaring a global variable

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

then passing this in scaffold key

```
 key: _scaffoldKey,
```

then finally replacing ModalBottomSheet `context` with `_scaffoldKey.currentContext`

```
context: _scaffoldKey.currentContext!,
```